# Castle Logging Facility In 2.0 Release

Tags: .net, open-source, logging, castle-windsor

Does anyone know if there are new binaries for the castle logging facility using the castle windsor 2.0 release?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windsor 2.1.1 (latest release as of this writing) now includes the Logging Facility.